# Can adiabatic processes decrease entropy (the Second Law as defined in Reif)?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, adiabatic

In Chapter 3.11 of the book "Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics" by F. Reif, the following is given as a definition of the Second Law of Thermodynamics:

1. In any process in which a **thermally** isolated system goes from one macrostate to another, the entropy tends to increase, i.e.,
   $$\Delta\geq 0$$
2. If the system is not isolated and undergoes a quasi-static infinitesimal process in which it absorbs heat , then
   $$=\frac{}{}$$

(Emphasis mine in the above.)

Now what I'm not sure about is what the term thermally is meant to mean here. Thus far, he has used the term thermally isolated to be synonymous with adiabatic. Does that then mean that there is no process by which a system's entropy can be decreased in an adiabatic (mechanical) interaction?

Comment: That's right.  If can only stay constant or increase.

Answer (score 3):

The only way the entropy of a system can decrease is by the transfer of heat to the surroundings. Consequently, the entropy of an adiabatic system cannot decrease.

The entropy of a system can increase in two ways. One is the transfer of entropy from the surroundings in the form of heat. That, of course, cannot occur for an adiabatic system. The other way is for entropy to be generated in the system. This can be the result of irreversible work, or the result of some spontaneous process (such as the free expansion of a gas) which by definition is irreversible, both of which are possible in an adiabatic system. Thus, for an adiabatic system, $\Delta S\ge 0$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why entropy cannot decrease when a system loses energy by doing work on its surroundings? This was not clear to me from Reif's explanation.

Comment: Sure, it’s because work  can’t  transfer entropy, only generate it when it is irreversible. Work is sometimes said to be “entropy free”.

Comment: Another way of putting it is work an organized form of energy transfer whereas heat is not

Answer (score 0):

If you are not clear on why a system's entropy cannot decrease when that system does work on its surroundings (in a reversible manner and without heat exchange) then my best advice as a teacher is to note that this is indeed true, and keep learning. Entropy is not an easy concept to get; you learn it partly by learning its properties, and this is one of them. The basic idea here is that entropy quantifies the degree to which the system has a large range of internal configurations all consistent with its macroscopic properties. When the system does work in a reversible manner without heat exchange, all these internal configurations adjust smoothly, and the number of them accessible to the system does not change.

Comment: Your point is well taken, but I suppose my concern is that Reif's book purports to make these macroscopic characterizations evident based on microscopic considerations. If the process is reversible, then it is quasi-static and so the inequality follows immediately from 2) above. But would you happen to have an explanation for why a system cannot do work in general (in particular, irreversibly) and decrease its entropy? Edit: To be clear, I'm wondering why a system can't decrease it's own entropy via work (while necessarily increasing the entropy of the system on which it does the work).

Comment: @1729_SR a quick answer is to say that if it did decrease its entropy via some process or other, then that process would not be called "work"! The separation between "heat" and "work" can be made precise in the thermodynamic limit; one reasons first about processes under conditions of zero heat flow, establishing that $U$ is a function of state, and then for other processes the defn of heat transfer is $\Delta Q = \Delta U - \Delta W$. One then goes on to use 2nd law to establish that reversible heat transfer, divided by $T$, is a change in a function of state (called entropy). See my book!

Comment: I may well do that, thank you for the heads-up! I've long been looking for a textbook that covers (classical) thermodynamics precisely and yet accessibly. Callen is intractable, whereas McQuarrie's physical chemistry text isn't quite rigorous enough. Does your text make contact with microscopic ideas at all (eg. entropy as a measure of accessible microstates, internal energy at a given temperature as a mean energy across microstates)?

Comment: @1729_SR it makes contact: yes, but only a little --- it is not a statistical mechanics text